# Should be there newSVuv instead newSVnv in perlxstut?

Tags: c, perl, xs

I'm just going through [perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) and I found there `newSVnv` in [EXAMPLE 5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html#EXAMPLE-5) and [EXAMPLE 6](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html#EXAMPLE-6) but I think that [`newSVuv`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Working-with-SVs) should be more appropriate. Curiously `newSVnv` works too. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it uses NVs (Perl's equivalent of a C `double`) instead of UVs (normally an `unsigned int`), because (depending on OS and compilation options), some of the values in a `struct statfs` might be 64-bit even though Perl is using 32-bit ints.  `newSVnv` works because the C compiler knows how to cast any integer type to a `double`.

You should be able to replace `newSVnv` with `newSVuv` for any member of `statfs` that will fit in a UV, and have it work just fine.  Perl converts between its numeric types automatically as needed.

Comment: So it means that `newSVnv` is considered safer version of `newSVuv` in Perl sense for Perl's automatic conversion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "safer".  There's no automatic conversion with the `newSV*v` functions (other than that done by the C compiler).  If you pass a `long long` to `newSVuv`, then you get whatever happens when your C compiler casts a `long long` to `unsigned int`.  A `double` has a greater range than any integer type, so you don't have to worry about a value that won't fit.

Comment: that is incorrect; many systems have 8 byte doubles (with 53 bites of precision) and 8 byte integers.  storing them in a double can lose precision.

Comment: @ysth, that's why I said "range" and not "precision".  You might lose precision when converting a large integer type to a `double`, but it won't be out of range.